# Статическая сборка Qt + CMake + qtpcre2

Tags: qt5, cmake

Доброго всем времени суток!

Есть некий проект Qt+CMake; собрал статический Qt5.12.12, хочу собрать приложение но не могу слинковать с qtpcre2.

В CMakeLists.txt:

```
link_directories(/opt/qt/qt51212-static/lib)
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} dl pthread z qtpcre2)
```

но линкер сообщает, что

```
cannot find -lqtpcre2
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как указать в CMakeLists.txt qtpcre2

Answer (score 0):

Либо

```
target_link_libraries(${TARGET} /abs/path/to/libqtpcre2)
```

либо

```
find_library(QTPCRE2 PATHS /path/to/dir/with/libqtpcre2.a)
if(NOT QTPCRE2)
   message(FATAL "libqtpcre2 not found)
endif()
target_link_library(${TARGET} ${QTPCRE2})
```